# Prevent the text going outside the containing <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow

I have this `styled-select` which I created due to my requirements. When one of the options is longer than the size of the containing `<div>` and I select it, it goes to the next line. I want it to be hidden and not scrollable. I've used `overflow(-x):hidden` but it did not work.

Here is the working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/qyf22h83/)

```js
 $(function() {

   $('.styled-select select').hide();
   $("select#elem").val('0');

   $('.styled-select div').each(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     $(this).html($container.find('select option:selected').text());
   });

   $('.styled-select div').click(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     var opLen = $container.find('select').children('option').length;
     if (opLen < 5) {
       $container.find('select').show().attr('size', opLen).focus();
     } else {
       $container.find('select').show().attr('size', 5).focus();
     }
   });

   $('.styled-select select').click(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     var text = $container.find('select option:selected').text();
     $container.find('div').html(text);
     $container.find('select').hide();
   });

   $('.styled-select select').focusout(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     $container.find('select').hide();
   });

 });
```

```css
 .styled-select select {
   position: absolute;
   background: transparent;
   width: 420px;
   padding-top: 5px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
   color: black;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 4;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -o-appearance: none;
   z-index: 1;
   outline: none;
   top: 42px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
 }
 
 .styled-select {
   background: url('../img/campaignSelector.png') no-repeat right;
   background-color: white;
   width: 420px;
   height: 42px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
   background-position: 97% 50%;
 }
 
 .styled-select option {
   font-size: 18px;
   background-color: white;
   margin-left: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="styled-select" style="width: 301px; margin:5px 0 0 10px;">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div id="userChannelDivId" style="font-size:18px; position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 5px; width: 300px; height: 42px;"></div>
  <select id="userChannelId" name="userChannelId" style="width:100%">
    <option value="">resh resh resh resh resh resh resh resh resh resh</option>
    <option value="">--- Belect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Celect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Delect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Felect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Gelect ---</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `overflow: hidden;` on the class `styled-select` itself. I also reduced the height of the container to 35px so there would be no trace of the second hidden line. See code below.

Another possibility is to add `white-space: nowrap` to the class `styled-select`'s style attribute. This way the text wouldn't wrap at all inside the div.

```js
 $(function() {

   $('.styled-select select').hide();
   $("select#elem").val('0');

   $('.styled-select div').each(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     $(this).html($container.find('select option:selected').text());
   });

   $('.styled-select div').click(function() {
     $('.styled-select').css('overflow', 'visible');
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     var opLen = $container.find('select').children('option').length;
     if (opLen < 5) {
       $container.find('select').show().attr('size', opLen).focus();
     } else {
       $container.find('select').show().attr('size', 5).focus();
     }
   });

   $('.styled-select select').click(function() {
     $('.styled-select').css('overflow', 'hidden');
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     var text = $container.find('select option:selected').text();
     $container.find('div').html(text);
     $container.find('select').hide();
   });

   $('.styled-select select').focusout(function() {
     $('.styled-select').css('overflow', 'hidden');
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     $container.find('select').hide();
   });

 });
```

```css
 .styled-select select {
   position: absolute;
   background: transparent;
   width: 420px;
   padding-top: 5px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
   color: black;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 4;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -o-appearance: none;
   z-index: 1;
   outline: none;
   top: 42px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
 }
 
 .styled-select {
   background: url('../img/campaignSelector.png') no-repeat right;
   background-color: white;
   width: 420px;
   height: 35px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
   background-position: 97% 50%;
 }
 
 .styled-select option {
   font-size: 18px;
   background-color: white;
   margin-left: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="styled-select" style="width: 301px; margin:5px 0 0 10px; overflow: hidden;">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div id="userChannelDivId" style="font-size:18px; position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 5px; width: 300px; height: 42px;"></div>
  <select id="userChannelId" name="userChannelId" style="width:100%">
    <option value="">resh resh resh resh resh resh resh resh resh resh</option>
    <option value="">--- Belect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Celect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Delect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Felect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Gelect ---</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you could listen to the user clicks and make overflow visible or hidden accordingly when the dropdown is open or closed. Check the updated code.